# akka-http mapResponse ignores some responses

Tags: scala, akka-http

Question about akka-http server. I have a top-level `mapResponse` which wraps all other routes. This `mapResponse` wraps all responses in the json. And recently I found that sometimes my server returns 503 error with plain-text explanation. I found that the reason is `akka.http.server.request-timeout` config value - it was too small. But why I didn't catch these responses with the top-level `mapResponse`? I found that this 503 response is created in `HttpServerBluePrint.TimeoutAccessImpl.apply` and it somehow ignores my `mapResponse`.

Here is the minimal reproduction code. I wrap all my routes in `logAndReturn200` function. I expect that all my routes will return `StatusCodes.OK`. But `/bar` returns timeout error.

```
val logAndReturn200 = mapResponse { response =>
  println(response)
  HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK)
}

val route = {
  logAndReturn200 {
    get {
      path("foo") {
        complete("OK")
      } ~
      path("bar") {
        val promise = Promise[Unit]()
        actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) {
          promise.success(())
        }
        onSuccess(promise.future) {
          complete("OK")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
```

Comment: It depends how exactly you structured your code, please provide the reproducer code

Comment: I added reproduction code in the question.